# Выборка MYSQL по условию из связной таблицы (YII2)

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, помогите сделать выборку между связующими таблицами, к примеру
есть две таблицы

```
tab1
project_id our_deposit
1           100
2           80
3           0     

tab2
id project_id amount
1      1        10
2      1        20
3      2        15
4      1        25
```

tab1 таблица с проетами и tab2 таблица с суммой выплат от вклада.

нужно выборкой получить проекты у которых сумма выплат к примеру больше 30 % ?

к примеру по 1 проекту мы вложили 100$ а получили tab2(10+20+25 = 55$) 
т.е получается 55$*100% / 100 = 55% то есть первый проект у нас попадает под это условие 
как правильно сделать выборку чтобы получить все проекты которые попадают под мои условия ?

PS использую yii2 но это не важно главное понять как сделать правильно выборку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычный `HAVING` с группировкой по проекту

```
SELECT
  tab1.project_id
FROM
  tab1
  JOIN tab2 ON (
    tab1.project_id = tab2.project_id
  )
GROUP BY
  tab1.project_id
HAVING
  SUM(tab2.amount) >= 0.3 * tab1.our_deposit
```

Comment: --Anton Shchyrov -- Спасибо большое, все получилось супер )

Comment: @Женя Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный